# Navigate Page to Page - Redirection issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, navigation

I try to make a web app which retrieve xml datas from database.
The database bind a first page Gridview with checkbox : 
[First page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRZO0.jpg)

The URL of this page is http://localhost:65224/**WebForm1**.aspx

The second page redirected by the "Validate" button is the result of the selected items from the first page with more details of what you have selected : 
[Page Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWGKu.jpg)

I don't know why, but the URL is the same that the last one : http://localhost:65224/**WebForm1**.aspx

The last "Validate" button is to confirm what you want to update, and i want to open a new page so as to confirm what user has selected from the checkbox (a summary), but the third page is totally empty.
And, the URL of this third page is, finally, correct : http://localhost:65224/**WebForm3**.aspx

There is a code behind for the second page, and that is why i have the results, but i don't know why the URL is not correct.

This the code behind the "OnClick" button of the WebForm2 :

```
protected void btn_final_validation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("WebForm3.aspx");
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gvResult.Rows)
        {

            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("FinalChk");
            CheckBox cb2 = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("FinalChkForm");

            if ((cb != null && cb.Checked) || (cb2 != null && cb2.Checked))
            {
                Server.Transfer("~/WebForm3.aspx");
                //cb2.Visible = false;
                //Response.Redirect("WebForm3.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                //ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Veuillez sélectionner au moins un item')", true);
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Scripts", "<script>alert('Vous devez sélectionnere au moins 1 item.');</script>");
            }
        }

        foreach (GridViewRow row in gvResultForm.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("FinalChkForm2");
            if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
            {
                Server.Transfer("~/WebForm3.aspx");
            }
        }

        foreach (GridViewRow row in gvResultFormSelected.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("FinalChk2");
            if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
            {
                Server.Transfer("~/WebForm3.aspx");
            }
        }
    }
```

And this the Page_Load code of the WebForm3 :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> test_recup = new List<string>();
        if (this.Page.PreviousPage != null)
        {
            GridView GridView1 = (GridView)this.Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("gvResult");

            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    CheckBox chkRow = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("FinalChk") as CheckBox);
                    CheckBox chkRow2 = (row.Cells[2].FindControl("FinalChkForm") as CheckBox);
                    if (chkRow.Checked)
                    {
                        string name = row.Cells[1].Text;
                        test_recup.Add(name);
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Template selected : " + name);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("recup_template", typeof(string));

        foreach (string s in test_recup)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(s);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("test : " + s);
        }

        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Server.Transfer` redirects on the server. i.e. the URL on the client doesn't reflect the actual page the server has returned. Change it to `Response.Redirect` if you want the client to know that a redirection has happened.

Comment: Is it possible to transfer the "CheckBox.Checked" information with "Response.Redirect" ? @CodeNinja  EDIT : i change "Server.Transfer" by "Response.Redirect" and the second page result is empty... but the URL is correct (WebForm2).

Comment: You can use query string to transfer it as a parameter while redirecting. I believe the empty page is due to the check - `this.Page.PreviousPage`.

Comment: Well, it doesn't really matter for me to have the good URL or not. I would like to transfer and bind the griview of my 3rd page from the selected data of my 2nd page. It works from 1 to 2, but not from 2 to 3, with the same code... is it "Cross Page Posting ?" [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/de41d6/navigation-techniques-in-Asp-Net/). I found that page on different navigation techniques but i have same issue. @CodeNinja

Comment: I manage to change the URL of the 2nd page. i erase the OnClick method and add `Page.PreviousPage.IsCrossPagePostBack`on Page_Load. Then, i add this on my aspx page : `<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/WebForm1.aspx" %>`. Unfortunatly, this changes doesn't work for the page, and i have the 2nd page only with no datas in it, when i click on the button.

Comment: `CrossPagePostBack` is for a different purpose. It's used when data from one page is posted to another using the ASP.Net web forms. If all you want is to bind data to grid based on the request coming from the previous page, I suggest you do so by adding a query string to the request when transferring request to the second page. You can find more about `CrossPagePostBack` in this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx)

Comment: i manage to display my 3rd WebForm with the good URL, but no data in it... first and second page are good with the good datas displayed. But the third one only display what i `DataTable.Rows.Add()` manually... i don't understand why my 2nd WebForms checkbox selections are not stored in my `List<string>` ... How is it possible ? @CodeNinja